# Java button start thread sets off other action listener

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, button

i'm trying to write code for a program which it starts to move automatically the mouse cursor when a JButton is pressed.
I'm having difficult because the stop condition is the type of any keyboard button, but when the thread for moving cursor starts, it doesn't handle the type event.

```
    private void initInterface() {

    frame = new JFrame("Let me sleep!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(CENTER_SCREEN_X - PANEL_WIDTH / 2, CENTER_SCREEN_Y - PANEL_HEIGHT / 2, PANEL_WIDTH,
            PANEL_HEIGHT);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    buttonStart = new JButton();
    buttonStart.setText("START Moving Cursor");
    buttonStart.setBounds(PANEL_WIDTH / 4, PANEL_HEIGHT / 4, PANEL_WIDTH / 2, 40);
    frame.add(buttonStart);
    frame.addKeyListener(this);

    
    /* buttonStart.addKeyListener(this); */
    buttonStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /* SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> letMeSleep.run());
            buttonStart.setText("Type any key to stop");
            
            Thread thread = new Thread( letMeSleep );
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> thread.run());
            */              
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    letMeSleep.run();
                    
                }});
            
        }
    });
}
```

LetMeSleep immplements Runnable interface and a logic which with class Robot, it moves the mouse cursor

Thanks at all!

Comment: *but when the thread for moving cursor starts, it doesn't handle the type event.*  - Key Events are only dispatched to the component with focus. When you click on the button the button has focus. Add the KeyListener to the button, not the frame.

Comment: Thanks camickr. It works!!
threadPool.submit is a correct way to call a new thread? Or there is a "best pratice"..the other attemps set the button always in a pressed state

Comment: You don't want the code to execute on the EDT. So you should be using the start() method of the Thread to start execution of your Runnable.

Comment: Great! now it works.

Comment: When `letMeSleep` is a `Runnable`, there is no point in implementing another `Runnable` just to invoke `letMeSleep`’s `run` method. Just use `threadPool.submit(letMeSleep);` You can simplify this further by using a lambda expression for the action listener, `buttonStart.addActionListener(e -> threadPool.submit(letMeSleep));`